# R Count Frequency of Custom Dictionary in a Dataframe Column but Group them

Tags: r, string, dataframe, text-mining, tweets

I have a task, which is too complex for my R-knowledge.
I have a dataframe with Tweets-data, including a column that consists of the usernames, data of the Tweet and the content of the Tweet.
It looks like this:
[Datastructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbTGd.png)

I have dictionaries of words like:

```
dict <- c("one", "two", "eleven")
```

I want to count the frequency of the words used within their tweets, but I want to group them by year and name.

I count the frequency by using this:

```
freq_auth <- tweetsanalysis1 %>% mutate(authority_dic = str_c(str_extract(text, str_c(authority_dic, collapse = '|')))) %>% count(authority_dic, name = 'freq_word') %>% arrange(desc(freq_word))
```

It works just like it should:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i1Pl.png)

But it counts for all names and dates. How do I count the frequency for every different name on their own and split it by year? I want to analyse each individual name on its word frequency and afterwards add the name and date of the tweet to the output.

Maybe cut the dataframe into tiny pieces by each name within a year and then run the analysis on each name? My dataset contains 30k observations and over 200 individual names, so that would take a lot of time.

I hope I was able to get my point across. If not, just ask me. :)
It would be greatly welcomed if someone would help me!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `group_by()` and `summarise()` and you can `spread()` after to create a column for each year.

See if this works for your:

```
freq_auth <- tweetsanalysis1 %>%
        mutate(authority_dic =str_c(str_extract(text, str_c(authority_dic, collapse = '|')))) %>%
        group_by(authority_dic, year, user_username) %>%
        summarise(freq_word = n()) %>% 
        arrange(desc(freq_word)) %>%
        spread(year, freq_word)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick help! That works perfectly for my first issue. Now I would need to do this on an individual level. Right now it analyses the whole dataset and I need it to group it also by the individual username. Do you know how I could implement it? 
Thank you so much for your solution for the first issue! Now only 50% is left!

Comment: Just add the user_username variable into group_by() function. I just edited the awnser

Comment: God bless you! It works perfectly fine. Ah, thank you so much!